# Zeta and Wn Values for Control

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I have a transfer function for control theory lecture. So the transfer function which is fifth (5.) order. How can I find $\zeta$ and $\omega_n$ values ?

For example :
${50 \over 60s^5+45s^4+85s^3-25s^2-758s}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you please write a more understandable question?can you write your attempts?

Comment: The denominator has three real roots and a complex pair. Compute the $\zeta, \omega_n$ for the complex pair.

Comment: I am glad to be here. As you know in control theory we have damping ratio (ζ) and natural frequency (Wn). Here is the transfer function and I need to find zeta and wn of this tf. But I do not want to result, I need to learn how to find if the tf is fifth order ? I mean, how to get solution for this ?

Comment: $\zeta$ and $\omega_n$ values are given for 2nd order systems. You can find approximate values for higher order systems by only taking the 2 poles that are closer to the imaginary line than other poles. This will give a good result if the other poles are far away from those 2 poles.

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed that your system is unstable?

You have negative coefficients in dominator!

This is the factorized form.

$$H(s)={50\over 60 s(s-1.60182) (1.85211 + s)(s^2+ 0.499706 s +4.25833 )}$$

Your transfer function does not look like second order transfer functions. No approximation makes sense in this case.

```
Octave / Matlab:

>> % pkg load control
>> H=tf(50,[60,45,+85,-25,-758,0]);
>> step(H,10)
```

[image: unstable system]